# Periodically check Solr is running on AWS instances (AWS monitoring)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, solr, cloud, monitoring

I'm trying to figure out how to monitor whether Solr is running on a group of EC2 instances. The way it works is as follows:

I have one app which contains a series of webapps. Each of these webapps uses Solr as their database, and Solr is split between 3 other servers in cloud mode:

```
Application EC2
 |
 |- Solr EC2 1
 |- Solr EC2 2
 |- Solr EC2 3
```

What would be ideal is, on the application server, periodically check the Solr status of the 3 Solr instances, e.g. run:

```
10.X.X.1:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS
10.X.X.2:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS
10.X.X.3:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS
```

and if any of them return a non-zero status then send an alert. I've looked into AWS CloudWatch but I'm not interested in process metrics I simply want to detect if it's running at all. All the custom check stuff I've found is for statistics rather than just outright running or not, so I can't check things like traffic out of the Solr isntances since sometimes the Solr instances aren't being used at all for days if no one's using a demo.

Any help welcome,

Thanks

Comment: you can use nagios for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I think the ideal approach would probably be to use a VPC-connected Lambda function that checks the site using a nodejs or python script and logs the response to cloudwatch using boto3 or the nodejs SDK. You can configure a Cloudwatch scheduled event (effectively a cronjob) to trigger the function every minute or so. The nice thing about Lambda functions, of course, is they're not tied to any servers you manage, but you will have to write a slightly more involved script.

Alternatively, you could just run a bash script run from your application server in a cronjob and use `aws cli` to report the data to Cloudwatch. As for the Cloudwatch reporting, you have a lot of flexibility in what data you report to Cloudwatch and how. Here is a simple example if you decide to use a cronjob running on a server:

```
url=<ip address of server>
curl -s -o /dev/null $url
result=$?
iso_date=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
region=us-east-1

# zero exit code becomes 1, failure becomes 0 for 
# reporting to cloudwatch
[[ $result -gt 0 ]] && response=0 || response=1

aws cloudwatch put-metric-data \
  --metric-name SiteUpOrDown \
  --namespace Solr \
  --timestamp ${iso_date} \
  --value ${response} \
  --dimensions "Server=${url}" \
  --unit None \
  --region $region
```

This should log to Cloudwatch either 0s or 1s for site being up or down. I would ultimately recommend something to monitor response time instead of just a binary result -- that way, you would actually have continuous data that would be more meaningful visually and in terms of gauging site performance. This command will return response time:

```
curl -s -w %{time_total}\\n -o /dev/null ${url}
```

You would still need to test for and appropriately respond to non-zero exit codes if using this, as this will return a value even if curl fails, which could be *very* misleading, but it would be a good start toward getting continuous data.

If you want to configure alerting, you can trigger a Cloudwatch alarm when 0s are reported and have those alerts go to an SNS topic and ultimately to an email address or some other endpoint.

You also need to make sure your permissions are configured correctly. Your ec2 instance profile or service account will need permission to write to Cloudwatch. If you use a Lambda function, it will also need those permissions, as well as the necessary permission and configuration to attach to your VPC subnets (there is a managed policy for this).

Comment: Just a quick note -- I was actually just able to validate that this is working for a test application, so I think you should be able to use this without much modification.

Comment: @Jayce444 Please mark this answer correct if it was helpful for you.